# Hard root beer way too foamy

Tags: root-beer

I brewed a hard root beer 2-3 months ago. Right from the start the beers have been way too foamy. I've had to pour each one into a pitcher in order to contain the foam. The basics of the recipe was a light ale with root beer concentrate and brown sugar added. The recipe called to mix the brown sugar cold. I didn't think that was right but did it anyhow. There is residue in each bottle that I think might be brown sugar that never dissolved. If it is brown sugar, could that be the cause of the foam. I want to do another batch, but want to correct the foamy issue.

Comment: Please specify the exact quantities of all ingredients.

Comment: Yes - what was the "light ale" part of the recipe? Root beer is often made from concentrate and sugar. Adding the ale seems a bit superfluous and the malts/dexrins will add to the foaming nature of the brew.

Comment: The whole thing was a mr beer kit. It consisted of a small can of american light LME, 2 root beer extract pouches and 2 cups of brown sugar. I'm sorry I don't have the exact sizes of lme and extract.

Answer (score 4):

No dissolved CO2 = no foam. Even the soapiest, lipid/protean saturated liquids don't foam if there are no included/dissolved gasses. So one thing to try is to reduce the amount of sugar added.

Dissolving the brown sugar in cold water is not unreasonable but dissolving it in (less volume of) boiled water and then diluting down will pasteurise the sugar to reduce the possible effect of other "wild" bacteria/fungi.

Unfortunately the question gives too little detail about process and ingredients to give a more accurate answer. How is this brew fermented? When is it bottled and what is the F.G of the bottled brew? What priming of the bottled brew (if any) is done?

Comment: Fermentation took about two weeks. The beer was then transferred to a bottling bucket and mixed with the root beer concentrate and 2 cups of brown sugar. I followed the instruction exactly being he first time. I couldn't mix the sugar briskly for fear of adding too much oxygen to the beer. I think there could have been some un-dissolved sugar that made its way in to the bottles. I didn't prime the bottles because I had just added so much sugar. The first few were just right, but everyone since then is a fountain of foam.